# Wrong Behavior of Relative Paths in Xcode Project When Adding New Files

Tags: xcode, file, project, relative-path

First of all, I am far from an Xcode guru and pretty much a newbie with it. The simplest thing have been bugging our team for quite sometime:

Whenever I had a new file to the project and select "Relative to Project" or "Relative to Enclosing Group" I will always get a semi-relative path. I get something in the line of:

***../../../../../Trunk/ProjectName/Sources/MyFile.h***

where as it should only be:

***../../../Sources/MyFile.h***

since the Xcode project is in the directory:

***/Dev/App/Trunk/ProjectName/Project/MAC/XCode/***

This is causing us alot of headaches since not every developer as their "Trunk" and "Project" directory labeled the same and XCode will then show these items in red since it can find them and won't allow the project to compile.

There is no way to obtain the expected relative path, even when I change the "Path Type" in the file info directly. The only solution is to manually edit the .xcodeproj.

The project roots is set to : "Project File Directory"

Is there anything else I am missing? This is using Xcode 3.2.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I've been seeing this problem recently in Xcode 3.2.3. I think it must be a recently introduced bug because this always used to work as expected in earlier versions. Hopefully it will be fixed when 4.0 eventually gets released, but you could always file a bug report at http://bugreporter.apple.com in the mean time. For now I've been fixing this manually by editing `project.pbxproj` to remove the redundant parts of the relative path.